# Spring Security Remember me with custom authentication provider

Tags: spring-security

I am using GWT with spring security. I have a custom authentication provider where I perform all my authentication. How can I configure the remember me feature without using the UserDetailsService? I am not using LDAP.

My AppliationContext_security.xml

```
<http auto-config="true" entry-point-ref="UnauthorizedEntryPoint"
    create-session="always">
    <form-login authentication-success-handler-ref="authenticationSuccessHandler"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <logout success-handler-ref="logoutSuccessHandler"
        invalidate-session="true" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**/myapp.rpc" access="ROLE_USER" />

    <custom-filter before="CONCURRENT_SESSION_FILTER" ref="XSRFAttackFilter" />

</http>

<authentication-manager>        
    <authentication-provider ref="myAuthenticationProvider" />
</authentication-manager>
```

In my custom authentication provider,

```
@Override
public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication)
        throws AuthenticationException {
    String username = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
    String password = (String) authentication.getCredentials();

    boolean response = loginmanager.authenticateUser(username, password,
            ((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder
                    .getRequestAttributes()).getRequest().getSession());
    if (!response) {
        throw new BadCredentialsException(
                "Invalid Credentials.");
    }

    Authentication authentication = ...
    authentication.setAuthenticated(true);

    return authentication;
}
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to create a custom `UserDetailsService` that gets the username/password from the same place that your `loginmanager` is reading it from.   See the source for `TokenBasedRememberMeServices.processAutoLoginCookie()` to see how it's being used.