# Spring Security - How to include "remember me" using custom authentication provider

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

I know for the feature of remember me you need to use `UserDetailsService`. but after going thought stackoverflow I found [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331784/spring-security-remember-me-with-custom-authentication-provider) which mentioned to use `UserDetailsService` in custom authentication provider. but i dont know how it is done. can anyone explain how implement `UserDetailsService` while using custom authentication provider for getting the remember me feature.